# After release AndroidX 1.0.0, the Room of Arch is still 2.0.0-rc01 different from lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions

Tags: android, android-jetpack, androidx

AndroidX 1.0 release is good, however,

androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions is now 2.0.0

androidx.room:room-runtime is still in 2.0.0-rc01 even not rc02

**Should the room-runtime** also be 2.0.0 or still pending?

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116402270

Comment: What is your question? "forget to push?" is not a question that we can answer here.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I should clear the question, I have edited the question. I just want to know why the Room is still in 2.0.0-rc not release.

Comment: We cannot answer that.